# I want to know the reference of the hadith about an ignorant person

Tags: hadith, fiqh, source-identification

Assalamualaikum! Is this hadith true that a man came to the Prophet(SAW) and asked that how could a person get hidayat if he had not listened about You SAW and lives in the forests or on mountains.The Rasoolullah SAW replied that he can find the oneness of Allah SWT by concentrating and thinking about the universe.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: I have never heard of such a hadith, nor could I find one based on the given information!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to mind my translations,
I've never heard of such hadith as well but I do know that, Allah will not judge some who was totally ignorant about Islam
and I quote from [IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/99144)
Allah said

> وَمَا كُنَّا مُعَذِّبِينَ حَتَّى نَبْعَثَ رَسُولاً {الإسراء: 15} صدق الله العظيم
>
> And never would We punish until We sent a messenger. ([17:15](http://legacy.quran.com/17/15))

and our prophet SAW said

> والذي نفس محمد بيده؛ لا يسمع بي أحد من هذه الأمة يهودي ولا نصراني ولم
> يؤمن بالذي أرسلت به إلا كان من أصحاب النار
>
> By Him in Whose hand is the life of Muhammad, he who amongst the community of Jews or Christians hears about me, but does not affirm his belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state (of disbelief), he shall be but one of the denizens of Hell-Fire. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:153))

Therefore, if we imagine that a person who lived his life and did not hear anything about Islam, it will be treated on the Day of Resurrection according to the people of his time.
Thus if he didn't ever heard of Islam, hewont be account disbeliever of it.